# What does the ampersand (&) before `self` mean in Rust?

Tags: variables, syntax, rust

I've seen this code in the Rust documentation:

```
fn eat(&self) {
    println!("{} is done eating.", self.name);
}
```

what does the `&` in `&self` mean?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

This means you'll be passing in a **reference** to the object, as opposed to moving the object itself. It's important to distinguish this because if your function looked like:

```
fn eat(self) {
    println!("{} is done eating.", self.name);
}
```

and you tried calling it *then* using the variable after, you'd get an error

```
object = Foo::new();
object.eat();
object.something(); // error, because you moved object in eat
```

because when you don't specify `&`, rust moves the value into the function and your original binding no longer has ownership. check out this minimal example I created ([playground version](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=struct%20Foo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20x%20%3A%20u32%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20Foo%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20eat(self)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22eating%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20something(%26self)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22else%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22Hello%2C%20world!%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20let%20g%20%3D%20Foo%20%7B%20x%3A%205%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20g.eat()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20g.something()%3B%20%20%2F%2F%20if%20this%20comes%20before%20eat%2C%20no%20errors%20because%20we%20arent%20moving%0A%7D&version=stable)):

```
struct Foo {
    x : u32
}

impl Foo {

    fn eat(self) {
        println!("eating");
    }

    fn something(&self) {
        println!("else");
    }

}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");

    let g = Foo { x: 5 };
    g.eat();
    g.something();  // if this comes before eat, no errors because we arent moving
}
```

Now switch `something` to be called **before** `eat`. Because `something` only takes a *reference*, `g` still has ownership and you can continue on. `eat` on the other hand moves `g` and you no longer can use `g`.

Comment: I think i got it. one thing I didn't get though is in the second example:
the function something: whay did you passed &self as a parameter. It is something you have to do to create function within mathoods(impl)?

Comment: @user3522940 I passed `&self` because I wanted to tell rust **not** to move the value. This way the variable retains ownership past the function call, try removing the `&` and you'll get the same error. It's important to note that a move is not a copy, it is literally a move